# comparing two tables using row id in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I want to get the data from second table where the row id is equal to first table?Can any one help me with the syntax or code ?

Comment: Do you mean [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing the two tables?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal no,i want to retrieve only second table data

Comment: Ok then `JOIN` the two tables and retrieve data only from the second table. Can you please edit your question with the table structures and some sample data.

Comment: If you want to retrieve only data from the second table, what has the first table to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do that.

You can use `join`:

```
Select t2.* 
from tab2 t2
join tab1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
```

also you can use `in` operator

```
Select * 
from tab2 t2
where t2.id in (  select t1.id
                  from table1 t1
               )
```

or you can use `exists` operator

```
Select * 
from tab2 t2
where exists
(
  selec 1
  from table1 t1
  where t2.id = t1.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged with `iPhone` `IOS` so this may be the query string

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM secondTable WHERE rowid = %d",yourRowID];
//where yourRowID is your first table id
```

But if you're talking about `Database` syntax then see this link [table joining](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/LEFT_JOIN) .